# Structuremap in MVC5

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, objectfactory

I'm using structuremap 3.1.2.138 in MVC5.
In my IoC-class i'm trying to use the Objectfactory but it states Objectfactory is obsolete and I should use Container but I can't find a way to make this work.

```
public static IContainer Initialize() {
        var BS_WebDataContextConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.Scan(scan =>
                    {
                        scan.Assembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    });

                //DataContext
                x.For<iBS_WebDataContext>().Use<BS_WebDataContext>()
                    .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
                    .Is(BS_WebDataContextConnectionString);

                //Repositories
                x.For<IReadOnlyEvidenceTypeRepository>().Use<EF6ReadOnlyEvidenceTypeRepository>();
                x.For<IReadOnlyStatusCategoryRepository>().Use<EF6ReadOnlyStatusCategoryRepository>();



                //Services
                x.For<IEvidenceTypeService>().Use<EvidenceTypeService>();
                x.For<IStatusCategoryService>().Use<StatusCategoryService>();


            });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
```

}

Could anyone give me an example how to **convert** this to the **container-way**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be done like so (including moving your configurations into a registry to keep it nice and tidy.

**WebsiteRegistry.cs**

```
public class WebsiteRegistry : Registry
{
    public WebsiteRegistry()
    {
        x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.Assembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });

        //DataContext
        var BS_WebDataContextConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        x.For<iBS_WebDataContext>().Use<BS_WebDataContext>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(BS_WebDataContextConnectionString);

        //Repositories
        x.For<IReadOnlyEvidenceTypeRepository>().Use<EF6ReadOnlyEvidenceTypeRepository>();
        x.For<IReadOnlyStatusCategoryRepository>().Use<EF6ReadOnlyStatusCategoryRepository>();

        //Services
        x.For<IEvidenceTypeService>().Use<EvidenceTypeService>();
        x.For<IStatusCategoryService>().Use<StatusCategoryService>();
    }
}
```

Then registered like so:

```
IContainer yourContainer = new Container();
yourContainer.Configure(c =>
{
    c.IncludeRegistry<WebsiteRegistry>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks JoeMighty. Works like a charm!
I just had to leave out the "x." because of the registry inheritance

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!